# How to use learning curves with random forests

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I've been going through Andrew Ng's machine learning course and just got done with the learning curve lecture. I created a learning curve for a logistic regression model I created, and it looks like the training and CV scores converge, which means my model could benefit from more features. How could I do a similar analysis for something like a random forest? When I create a learning curve for a random forest classifier with the same data in sklearn my training score just stays very close to 1. Do I need to use a different method of getting the training error?

Answer (score 0):

Learning Curves is a tool to learn about [bias-variance-trade-off](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html). Since your random forest model training score stays very close to 1, your random forest mode l is able to learn underlying function. If your underlying function was more non-linear, more complex, you would have had to add more features. See following [example](http://www.astroml.org/sklearn_tutorial/practical.html), figure Learning Curves.

Start with only 2 features and train your random forests model. Then use all of your features and train random forests your model.
You should see similar graph for your example.